# How do I get everything after a certain index in string c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

Lets say I have the string:

"MyNamespace.SubNameSpace.MyClassName"

How do I extract just everything after the last period, "MyClassName"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use **[String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx)** and **[String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w96zd3d.aspx)** methods.

```
string str = "MyNamespace.SubNameSpace.MyClassName";
string str1 = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Comment: +1 for adding the +1 to get everything *after* the last period.

Comment: If i need only Space from the SubNameSpace, how to get that?

Answer (score 0):

C# also range operation.
Here's another way to do it, not that it's particularly any better than what was already suggested:

```
string str = "MyNamespace.SubNameSpace.MyClassName";
string str1 = str[(str.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)..];
```