# Given a specific index number of a string, how can I get the complete word in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string

For example, I have this string "This is a trial string", and I know that I want the word which is at position 2 (in this case, the word "This"). The letter at index 2 of the whole string is part of the word "This", so I want to get that word. In case I supply the index of a separator, then I wouldn´t get any specific word, just the separator.

How can do this? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543273/how-do-i-get-everything-after-a-certain-index-in-string-c-sharp) link, but it shows how to get everything AFTER a certain index, I need the word AT a certain index.

Comment: "This" is not at position 2. What do you mean?

Comment: Maybe you can search for whitespace before and after? (an IndexOf variant)

Comment: I think he means that the letter at index 2 of the whole string is part of the word "This".  I could be wrong, though - it is a little bit vague - what happens if you supply the index of a separator (space)?  Which word do you use?

Comment: Or you can iterate yourself until you pick whitespace.

Comment: are all the words seperated by a space? if so, try string.split() method to cut your sentece in pieces which can be seen by index

Comment: Of course it depends on your requirements (safety, speed, readability, pick two... ;)).

Comment: @ZombieSheep Already edited, that is exactly what I meant sorry for not being specific enough!

Comment: @Moonlight Yes, all words are separated by a space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make an extension method that checks for spaces:

Call like this: `string theWord = myString.GetWordAtPosition(18);`

```
    static class WordFinder
    {
        public static string GetWordAtPosition(this string text, int position)
        {
            if (text.Length - 1 < position || text[position] == ' ') return null;

            int start = position;
            int end = position;
            while (text[start] != ' ' && start > 0) start--;
            while (text[end] != ' ' && end < text.Length - 1) end++;

            return text.Substring(start == 0 ? 0 : start + 1, end - start - 1);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Worked! Also a small detail, `return text.Substring(start == 0 ? 0 : start + 1, end - start-1);` so as not to return the last whitespace!

Comment: And add the test `if (end > start)` before returnung the result. The position might be pointing at a space!

Answer (score 2):

You could store the starting indexes of words in array (or hashtable) such as:

```
0 : The
6 : is
9: a
11: trial
17: string
```

And then compare it with the index you need.

**Upd. Example added of finding indexes:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var str = "This is a trial string";
    var words = str.Split(new [] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var list = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        list.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(str.IndexOf(word), word));
    }
}
```

Variable `list` will contain all indexes.

Comment: @Ray. You may use different approaches: split into words and find their indexes with IndexOf or use recursively IndexOf().

Comment: have a look at my solution without using an additional list to keep the indexes

Answer (score 2):

Use RegEx and Linq to get the words, and find the word (i.e. Match) where the start index and length bound the position of your character:

```
static string GetWord(String input, int charIndex) {
    if (charIndex > (input.Length - 1)) { throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(); }
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(input[charIndex].ToString(), @"\w")) {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            String.Format("The character at position {0} is not in a word", charIndex));
    }
    return (
        from Match mx in Regex.Matches(input, @"\w+")
        where (mx.Index <= charIndex) && ((mx.Index + mx.Length - 1) >= charIndex)
        select mx).Single().Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the word at the character position you could do this:

```
        string input = "This is a trial string";
        int position = 2;

        var words = input.Split(' ');

        int characterCount = 0;
        for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words.Length; wordIndex++)
        {
            var word = words[wordIndex];
            if (characterCount + word.Length + wordIndex > position)
                return word;
            characterCount += word.Length;
        }

        return null;
```

This returns the word after the space if the index corresponds to a space.

Answer (score 1):

```
string sString = "This is a trial string";
int iPos = 3;
int iBegin = -1, iEnd = 0;

if (sString[iPos] == ' ') // Character is space, no word?
    return;

for (int i = iPos; i >= 0; i--)
    if (sString[i] == ' ')
    {
       iBegin = i+1;
       break;
    }

if (iBegin == -1) // in case of first word
    iBegin = 0;

for (int i = iPos; i < sString.Length; i++)
    if (sString[i] == ' ') 
    {
        iEnd = i-1;
        break;
    }

string sWord = sString.Substring(iBegin, iEnd-iBegin+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

how about (untested and unoptimised)...

```
string GetWordAtIndex(string original, int position)
{
    int startPoint = original.Substring(0,position).LastIndexOf(" ");
    if(startPoint < 0) startPoint = 0;
    int endPoint = original.Substring(position).IndexOf(" ") + position;
    return original.Substring(startPoint, endPoint-startPoint);
}
```

doesn't check for the word being the last in the original string, either, which may throw an out of bounds error.  Just need to check if endPoint == -1 and adjust accordingly

Comment: Worked! Only detail: at the end `return original.Substring(startPoint-1, endPoint-startPoint);`, in order to return the string without the whitespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
string WordAtIndex( string myString, int chosenIndex)
{
     char[] cArray = myString.ToCharArray();

     int currentWordCount = 0;

     //return an empty string if the index is whitespace.
     if (cArray[chosenIndex] == ' ')
         return string.Empty;

     for (int i = 0; i < chosenIndex; i++)
     {
         if (cArray[i] == ' ')
             currentWordCount++;
     }

     return myString.Split(' ')[currentWordCount];
}
```

To use:

```
string word = WordAtIndex("This is a trial string", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version:

```
var firstPos = str.LastIndexOf(' ', index) + 1;
var lastPos = str.IndexOf(' ', index);
var word = lastPos == -1 ? str.Substring(firstPos)
                         : str.Substring(firstPos, lastPos - firstPos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
    string GetWordFromIndex(string value, int index)
    {

        int scannedIndex = 0;
        return  value.Split().First<string>(str =>
        {

            scannedIndex += str.Length;
            if (index < scannedIndex)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        });

    }
```

use like

```
var result = GetWordFromIndex( "This is a trial string", 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the fastest solution

```
public static string GetWord(string str,int index) {
            var vettWord = str.Split(' ');
            int position=0;
            foreach(var item in vettWord){
                if ( index<= position+item.Length)
                {
                    return item;
                }
               position += item.Length+1; // +1 to consider the white space
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
```

I have tried it

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string s = "This is a trial string";
            Console.WriteLine(GetWord(s, 17)); //string
            Console.WriteLine(GetWord(s, 2)); // This
            Console.WriteLine(GetWord(s, 9)); // a
        }
```