# C# Detect file type without a extension without long code or a dictonary

Tags: c#

How can I detect what the file is without a extension being opened with just a openfiledialog without really long dictionary code just a simple 1-5 line code that detects it?

Comment: just a open file dialog

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2543281/833070
`string str = "file.xls";`
`string type = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);`

Will return XLS, so you know it's an Excel file. It does require knowledge of each extension that could be used. But there is little way around that sadly

Answer (score 2):

Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx

You have the filename from your open dialog, pass it the name as the parameter, you will end up with the extension